# Undo automatic update

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

I was working with Predict function (with a neural network and today, and when I executed the same notebook I have been working for some time, Machine Learning package was automatically updated (it was shown the usual popup informing about a connection to Wolfram server for updating).

My problem is that now that now the same predict function does not give the same results. And it fact

So, is it possible to undo an updated function or package?

Comment: I fear that this may not be possible.  You could *try* uninstalling and reinstalling *Mathematica*, and turning of data updates, but I don't think `Predict` will work without and initial network acquisition which presumably would be the current version.  You might try contacting WRI about this.

Comment: Well, now I'm manually setting some parameters, and luckily I'm getting better results. But thanks anyway.